# .net core web api - How to return table results in chunks

Tags: .net-core, asp.net-web-api

We're returning tens of thousands of results to an end user when they load a table. We want to return all the data, so that filters and sorting can happen client side. The initial load can be a bit slow depending on the users connection.

To speed this up, I would like to return the data in chunks, a few thousand rows at a time and add them when ready. Sorting and filtering would need to wait until this is complete, but at least the end user would be able to see results whilst they are waiting. Is there a way using async perhaps to return results in chunks? Ideally it would first return some summary information, such as total results first.

Comment: `async` isn't streaming. HTTP doesn't allow streaming results anyway, that's available in gRPC. What you can do in HTTP is *paging* - requesting a specific page of data at a time. You can implement paging yourself (all it needs is an offset and count parameter) or you can create a GraphQL or OData service where paging is part of the protocol itself.

Comment: With ASP.NET Core 6 you can stream JSON responses without buffering (`IAsyncEnumerable`). Client side code will need to be adapted to be able to process such response

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes I know that! Paging is not a suitable solution to meet our business requirements - it would remove some of the interactivity and predictive filtering.

Comment: @AlekseyL. Thanks I will look into that too. https://www.tpeczek.com/2021/07/aspnet-core-6-and-iasyncenumerable.html looks like an interesting read on it.

Comment: @trees_are_great why would it? The user won't even notice the difference if you use infinite scrolling. The answer you accepted doesn't solve this problem though. It solves the problem of double buffering and waiting for all results before returning them. If the client is an API, that's more than enough. If the client is a browser though, the 17K row table will cause significant delays. Even if you use a grid like ag-Grid, this will still take space as a JS array. And if you use ag-Grid, virtualization/infinite scrolling is already available. And filtering

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos we do have paging on the client side, along with smart filtering and summary tables with graphs. All results will need to be client side for some of the things to work, for example smart filtering, but showing some data immediately, will be more useful that showing a loading spinner. For example, when a filter is applied, we want to know all the values available on another property that you can filter on. We allow saving of filters, so most of the time, the returned result set will be a lot smaller, but improving the initial response time will still be helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use yield return for return chunks of data, like below.

```
 public class ValuesController : ApiController
        {
            [HttpGet]
            public IEnumerable<ReturnModel> Get()
            {
                // An example of returning large number of objects
                foreach (var i in Enumerable.Range(0, 10000))
                    yield return new ReturnModel() { SequenceNumber = i, ID = Guid.NewGuid() };
            }
        }
```

Use this [Link](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1180464/Large-JSON-Array-Streaming-in-ASP-NET-Web-API) for reference!